# How to put a "/" in AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to write a AHK script that sends text to the command prompt. When I send "ipconfig /all" this is what shows up in the command prompt "ipconfig `all". I cant get it to put the "/" in. I have tried the COMSPEC and escape characters. But still cant figure it out.

Below is my current code.

```
^!d:: ; Ctrl, Alt, d

Run, C:\Users\Alex Chapman\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WinX\Group3\02 

sleep 500

Clipboard = ipconfig /all

send, ^v

send, {Enter}

return
```

Comment: `send ipconfig /all` works4me. Might be something else in the code like SetKeydelay or SendMode or ...

Comment: Thats how I am typing it. Also I am not using any SetKeydelay or SendMode

Comment: Your code is working fine here (besides the Run because I don't have this file on my Windows VIsta);

Answer (score 1):

These 4 ways to do it work for me:

Normal: `Send ipconfig /all`

Escaped: `` Send ipconfig `/all ``

Raw: `SendRaw ipconfig /all`

and the workaround:

```
clipboard=ipconfig /all
Send ^v
```

If you want to preserve your clipboard using the workaround you can do the following:

```
cbbackup:=clipboard
clipboard=ipconfig /all
Send ^v
clipboard:=cbbackup
cbbackup=
```

Comment: Thanks! The clipboard was the only one that worked .

Comment: @A.Chapman Only the clipboard works? So there must be something else going on. Do you have any other hotkeys or hotstrings that may be interfering? Are you using a standard keyboard/standard layout?  Substituting a backtick `\`` for a `/` doesn't sound like any AHK feature . . .

Comment: @A.Chapman Maybe one of your hotkeys (in this script or in another current running) is something like ``$/:: Send ` `` so your `Send ipconfig /all` command is firing the hotkey instead of sending the key... can you share your code please? This behavior is very strange...